# Swift Flow - Hiding Tables/Unhiding Tables, isHidden

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting inconsistencies when it come to Swift flow, hiding a UITableView and reloading it.  I'm hiding the table at function launch, but there are certain instances when running the function that the table and searchBar won't hide before reloading the table.  I set breakpoints to see if table hides before reloading, but it always seems to hide far later than I imagine.

Am I misunderstanding swift flow with tables?  Here is the code of my function:

```
@objc func sportsChange() {
    reloadTab = 1
    spinnerView.isHidden = false
    self.rosterTable.isHidden = true
    self.searchBar.isHidden = true
    if(selectedSport == fbSport){
        theUserDefaults.set(bbSport, forKey: "sportDefault")
        selectedSport = theUserDefaults.string(forKey: "sportDefault")
        sportLogo = sportBbLogo
        theUserDefaults.set(sportBbLogo, forKey: "sportLogo")

    }
    else if(selectedSport == bbSport){
        theUserDefaults.set(fbSport, forKey: "sportDefault")
        selectedSport = theUserDefaults.string(forKey: "sportDefault")
        theUserDefaults.set(sportFbLogo, forKey: "sportLogo")
        sportLogo = sportFbLogo
    }
    let sportImageSet = UIImage(named: sportLogo!)
    sportsIcon.setImage(sportImageSet , for: .normal)
    let sportButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: sportsIcon)
    let currWidth = sportButton.customView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
    currWidth?.isActive = true
    let currHeight = sportButton.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
    currHeight?.isActive = true
    sportsIcon.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sportsChange), for: .touchUpInside)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.rosterUrl = getRosterUrl(server: server, tid: teamid, yr: currentYearStr, sp: selectedSport!)
        self.finalParse(getTheUrl: self.rosterUrl)
        self.rosterTable.reloadWithAnimation()
        self.rosterTable.isHidden = false
        self.searchBar.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "Swift flow".

Answer (score 0):

Because your function `reloadWithAnimation` is sync so `self.rosterTable.isHidden = false` will be called right after reloading. Also there are a lot of strange things in this method (setting constraints, hiding views twice etc.)

Comment: So where should I unhide the table?  With a completion?

Comment: I am not sure that you should reload table at all. User won't see it anyway. So you need to reload your table only in case of your data was changed.

Comment: Yes, the data is changing.  The finalParse function is updating the array for the table.

Comment: But you will hide your table. So you could change your array but won't reload the table view

Comment: Oh, I guess I didn’t know that.  If you update the array, you do t need to reload the table?

Comment: We don't need to update the table because user can't see it (we will hide it).